# Pytest plugin: Overriding pytest_runtest_call and friends

Tags: python, plugins, pytest

I'm developing a test suite using pytest for a project of mine. Because of the nature of the project, I need to create a Pytest plugin that controls how the tests are being run; they are not run locally, but sent to a different process to run. (I know about `xdist` but I think it doesn't solve my problem.)

I've been writing my own Pytest plugin by overriding the various `pytest_runtest_*` methods. So far it's been progressing well. Here is where I've hit a wall: I want my implementations of `pytest_runtest_setup`, `pytest_runtest_call` and `pytest_runtest_teardown` to actually be responsible for doing the setup, call and teardown. They're going to do it in a different process. **My problem is:** After Pytest calls my `pytest_runtest_setup`, it also calls all the other `pytest_runtest_setup` down the line of plugins. This is because the hook specification for `pytest_runtest_setup` has `firstresult=False`.

I don't want this, because I don't want `pytest_runtest_setup` to actually run on the current process. I want to be responsible for running it on my own. I want to **override** how it's being run, not **add** to it. I want the other implementations of `pytest_runtest_setup` below my own to **not** be run.

How can I do this?

Comment: It seems like you'll have to monkeypatch some obscure function on pytest.  Tried to look at the code for a bit and didn't seem obvious when that function is called. Maybe there's a cleaner, more compatible solution than monkeypatching, though.

Comment: I don't have time to come up with a working example before the bounty expires, but it looks like the hook to do this is: [`pytest_runtest_protocol`](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/writing_plugins.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_runtest_protocol)

Answer (score 0):

[Generic “runtest” hooks](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/writing_plugins.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_runtest_protocol)

All runtest related hooks receive a pytest.Item object.

pytest_runtest_protocol(item, nextitem)[source]

```
implements the runtest_setup/call/teardown protocol for the given test item, including capturing exceptions and calling reporting hooks.
Parameters: 

    item – test item for which the runtest protocol is performed.
    nextitem – the scheduled-to-be-next test item (or None if this is the end my friend). This argument is passed on to pytest_runtest_teardown().

Return boolean: 

True if no further hook implementations should be invoked.
```

pytest_runtest_setup(item)[source]

```
called before pytest_runtest_call(item).
```

pytest_runtest_call(item)[source]

```
called to execute the test item.
```

pytest_runtest_teardown(item, nextitem)[source]

```
called after pytest_runtest_call.
Parameters: nextitem – the scheduled-to-be-next test item (None if no further test item is scheduled). This argument can be used to perform exact teardowns, i.e. calling just enough finalizers so that nextitem only needs to call setup-functions.
```

pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call)[source]

```
return a _pytest.runner.TestReport object for the given pytest.Item and _pytest.runner.CallInfo.
```

For deeper understanding you may look at the default implementation of these hooks in _pytest.runner and maybe also in _pytest.pdb which interacts with _pytest.capture and its input/output capturing in order to immediately drop into interactive debugging when a test failure occurs.

The _pytest.terminal reported specifically uses the reporting hook to print information about a test run.