# Example of generic runtest hooks for pytest framework

Tags: python, pytest

I am new to pytest, trying to explore and understand how following generic `runtest` hooks work:

```
pytest_runtest_setup
pytest_runtest_call
pytest_runtest_teardown
```

I have referred pytest documentation but couldn't find solid examples to under above 3. It will be great if someone can provide a working example/demo or a reference link if available. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the default implementation in `_pytest.runner`: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/_modules/_pytest/runner.html

You can also refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38823263/3858507

In general, `pytest_runtest_setup` / `teardown` implement setup or teardown for tests that the plugin runs for (much like setup and teardown for test classes).

`pytest_runtest_call` actually runs the test.